# I want to know how many request per second my server can handle?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I want to know how many HTTP requests per second my server can handle using Jmeter.

I got throughput 128/mins which means 2/3 req per sec. but something is wrong in my sampler can you tell what I need to do to test the login URL?

Answer (score 5):

Hammering a login page doesn't have anything in common with the [load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) as load testing is checking your application against the **anticipated** load.

If you're trying to determine the maximum number of requests per second your server can handle - this is some form of [stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing)

In both cases you should come up with a realistic test scenario which would represent [real users using real browsers](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) like:

1. Record your scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. Perform [parameterization and correlation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)
3. Run your test with several virtual users/iterations and inspect request/response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing
4. Once you're happy with your test script - disable the View Results Tree listener and run full load test using [command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/)
5. Analyze your results using [JMeter Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

With regards to your goal I would recommend increasing the load **gradually** so you would be able to correlate the increasing number of users with the increasing throughput.

When you reach the point where you're adding more users and the throughput doesn't increase - it means that the application cannot handle more load hence that would be the maximum number of users/requests per second your application can handle.